# In what specification was Promise.all introduced?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to document the solution of a common interview question and how the solution has changed with language updates.

For example, const & let were introduced in ES2015 making the problem easier to solve.

At what specification year was Promise.all introduced?

**Related Code**

```
// solution using promises
//
function asyncMap(tasks, callback){
  tasks = tasks.map(task => new Promise(task))
  return Promise.all(tasks)
    .then(callback);
}


// solution using let and const introduced in ES2015
// released in 2015 and sometimes referred to as ES6
function asyncMap1(tasks, callback) {
  const results = [];
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    tasks[i](function (val) {
      results[i] = val;
      count++;
      if (count === tasks.length) {
        callback(results);
      }
    });
  }
};


// before let was available an IIFE would be needed
//
function asyncMap2(tasks, callback) {
  var results = [];
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
      tasks[i](function (val) {
        results[i] = val;
        count++;
        if (count === tasks.length) {
          callback(results);
        }
      });
    })(i);
  }
};
```

Comment: Introduction time is a little tidbit but browser support is what matters most.

Comment: agree completely but how would you quantify this?  the date that Chrome implements it perhaps?

Comment: According to this link ... https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_promise_all ... Chrome supported it before the spec.

Comment: it's not only about implementing but browser usage. If a feature is implemented in the newest version but many people still use previous versions, it doesn't matter much. Anyways, babel + browserslist allows you to use newest features without worrying about browser versions. So I'd say the creation of babel plugin of a feature is the most important ;)

Comment: a new feature must be supported in at least one browser (mostly behind a flag now) before it gets into EcmaScript. It's part of how new features are introduced to the language.

Comment: what do you mean "behind a flag"

Comment: chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the [specification document](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all) it was at ES2015. More specific at June 2015.

> ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification
>
> > 25.4.4.1 Promise.all ( iterable )

If you also want to know if you can use it, just ask it at **Can I Use** or follow [this link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_promise_all).

Comment: I googled it but could not find it so quickly, for example the MDN doc points to the latest specification ES2020.  How did you find this?

Comment: @j.a. You probably followed this [link](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise.all), but I've used the [pt-br version](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Especifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es) of MDN.

Comment: ... interesting ... Chrome supported it before the spec ... https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_promise_all